# SonarQube Out of Memory Exception during importing of results C# scan

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**SonarQube issue**

I'm trying to analyze a fairly large project (1.5m LOC) and getting Out Of Memory exceptions during the importing results from proto files stage (Visible in attached screenshot).  I am following these steps for scanning C# code: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

This method works for smaller projects but unfortunately not for this combined larger project.  I tried setting the Xmx value higher as described here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN#AnalyzingSourceCode-F.A.Q. to no avail.

Are there other possible sonar properties that I can try adding to help alleviate this issue? We are running the commands on a Windows machine and the SQ server is Version 6.7.1 (build 35068).

[Failure during importing of results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZsVB.png)